# How to store and handle big data string (around 2mb) in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a frontend in angular and the API is in nodejs. The frontend sends me the encrypted file and right now I am storing it in MongoDB. But when I send this file to a frontend, the call will sometimes break. So please suggest me how can I solve this call break issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't particularly clear.  As I understand it, you want to send a large file from the Node backend to the client.  If this is correct, then read on.

I had a similar issue whereby a long-running API call took several minutes to compile the data and send the single large response back to the client.  This issue I had was a timeout and I couldn't extend it.

With Node you can use 'streams' to stream the data as it is available to the client.  This approach worked really well for me as the server was streaming the data, the client was reading it.  This got round the timeout issue as there is frequent 'chatter' between the server and client.

Using Streams did take a bit of time to understand and I spent a while reading various articles and examples.  That said, once I understood, it was pretty straightforward to implement.

This article on [Node Streams](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/node-js-streams-everything-you-need-to-know-c9141306be93) on the freeCodeCamp site is excellent.  It contains a really useful example where it creates a very large text file, which is then 'piped' to the client using streams.  It shows how you can read the text file in 'chunks', make transformations to those checks and sent it to the client.  What this article doesn't explain is how to read this data in the client...

For the client-side, the approach is different from the typical fetch().then() approach.  I found another article that shows a working example of reading such streams from the back-end.  See [Using Readable Streams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_readable_streams) on the Mozilla site.  In particular, look at the large code example that uses the 'pump' function.  This is exactly what I used to read the data from streamed from the back-end.

Sorry I can't give a specific answer to your question, but I hope the links get you started.